# Vim doesn't use tabstop distance in insert-mode

Tags: vim, lisp, auto-indent

I'm having problems with auto indentation in vim while programming in lisp.

My .vimrc had the following settings for tabs:

```
set noexpandtab
set autoindent
set softtabstop=0
set shiftwidth=8
set tabstop=8
```

When I type `(if <enter>` in insert-mode, a new line is created with an indentation of **two spaces**.
None of my settings say anything about two spaces, so why don't I get a tab?
What setting can I use to change the indentation while in insert-mode?

Thanks in advance!

Update:
Thanks for the answers, the settings are not overwritten.
It has to do with the "default lisp indenting".
In the `:help lisp` it says something about changing the `p` flag in
`cpoptions`. This is what it says in the help for the `cpoptions` flags:

```
p - Vi compatible Lisp indenting.  When not present, a slightly better algorithm is used.
```

Setting it does change the indent to one space instead of two spaces.
Still not sure how to change this to something else though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with lisp but it looks like Vim handles lisp indenting as a special case. You could take a look at `:help 'lisp'`.

Comment: Thanks gdupras, I looked at the help for lisp, managed to get a different indentation, but not sure how to change it to what I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is two-space indentation is a hard coded behavior of `:set lisp` mode which ignores `shiftwidth`.

We can trace this to the [source code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/4490ec4e839e45a2e6923c265c7e9e64c240b805/src/indent.c#L1977) which contains a hard-coded `amount += 2;` increment statement.

It's that way for a good reason; it has come to be the predominant way of writing Lisp.

As I wrote this answer, I peeked at samples of source code the following projects (all Lisp or Lisp-like languages):

- Steel Bank Common Lisp (SBCL);
- Clozure Common Lisp (CCL);
- GNU Emacs;
- Clojure;
- GNU Guile;
- Racket;
- and GNU CLISP.

I did not spot a single example of anything but two-space indentation! With two-space indentation, you are in good/large company. You might as well get used to that; even if you somehow get Vim to follow your way, if you upstream anything into anyone's Lisp project, you will likely have to reformat.

Now, I have seen Lisp code using four-space indentation, like in very old code bases and some books.

By the way, sometimes you see `if` indented like this:

```
(if (condition)
    (then)
    (else))
```

This may happen where indentation is four spaces, but I'm referring situations when this is alignment, and not four space indentation. This formatting is, of course, standard for function arguments, but controversial for operators such as `if`. Some people like it that way in their code bases. For instance, this institution's [randomly found coding style guide](https://dept-info.labri.fr/%7Estrandh/Teaching/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html) recommends this way of writing `if`, while also recommending two-space indentation.

Vim will do the above if you remove `if` from `lispwords`.

The `:set lispwords=...` parameter contains a comma-separated list of identifiers which follow operator-like indentation, meaning two spaces rather than function-like alignment: second and third lines align with argument. By default, `if` is found in `lispwords`.

Lisp mode also applies two space indentation to a function (i.e. form not listed in `lispwords`, if there is no argument):

```
(gobbledygook 1 2 
              2 3)

(gobbledygook
  1)
```

That's also "canonical". Sometimes this comes in handy if you're trying to conform to some maximum line length; a function call running past the limit can sometimes be made to fit by moving all its arguments down, and just giving them two space indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Each filetype can have its own settings in vim. So your .vimrc values can be overwritten in filetype plugins. To learn the current values of the settings for lisp filetype open the lisp file and run the following commands in vim command line:

```sh
:set noexpandtab?
:set autoindent?
:set softtabstop?
:set shiftwidth?
:set tabstop?
```

If they are different from the ones in .vimrc, then your values are overwritten in some plugin.

In order to overwrite them again with your custom values, create the `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/lisp.vim` file with the required values:

```
set noexpandtab
set autoindent
set softtabstop=0
set shiftwidth=8
set tabstop=8
```

Comment: You can find out, where your setting is changed by using `verbose` -> `:verbose set noexpandtab?`. There is no need about speculations where your stuff is overwritten. But I agree with you, it is most likely the filetype plugin.

Comment: The settings aren't overwritten, so it must be somewhere else.
I didn't see anything in the lisp.vim file about indentation, but that might also be because that file is quite confusing to read :-).